# grep -E mismatching subdomains with mailids

Tags: grep, regular-expression

In my Apache access log I want to find all URLs matching `*.google.com`. I tried this with `grep -E *.google.com` but it also matched `mailid@google.com`, which is not desired. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

The `*` at the beginning makes no sense. `.` in a regular expression matches anything, i.e. it matches the `@` in the address. To match literal dot, use `\.`.

```
echo mailid@google.com | grep -E '\.google\.com' || echo no match
```

Comment: Can I use, grep -E '*\.google\.com' to match all subdomains.

Comment: Why do you put the `*` at the beginning? `*` means *repeat the preceding item 0 or more times* , it makes no sense to repeat nothing.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it, a valid domain name contains letters, numbers and hyphen. Try this:

```
grep -E '[[:alnum:]-]+\.google\.com'
```

Search for regular expression tutorials, that will help you.

Comment: which is equivalent to `grep '[[:alnum:]-]\.google\.com'`

Comment: Missing the `\+` quantifier

Comment: No, I do mean it's functionnaly equivalent to `grep '[[:alnum:]-]\.google\.com'` without the `+`. (`\+` is a GNU extension). Both match on `@@@x.google.com` for instance.

Comment: Right of course. I had another Q on my mind